# Conditional for a field generated by a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT
        Req_PK, 
        Req_PostDate, 
        Req_code, 
        Req_CreateDate, 
        Req_FillDate, 
        Req_Canceldate, 
        Req_Hold, 
        (
            Select Convert(varchar(50),Count(CanReq_PK)) 
            From CanReq 
            Where CanReq_ReqFK = Req_PK) AS Applications, 
        Req_PublishstatusFK 
FROM Req
WHERE Req_Filled <> 1 
AND Req_Cancelled <> 1 
AND Req_Template <> 1 
AND Req_PublishstatusFK = 1 
AND Req_publishstatusfk = 1
```

How do I modify this query so the Applications field/alias is not the everything returned by the SELECT statement but everything except the ones with value '0'?

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Wrap your query up in a derived table. Apply the Applications condition on its result.

Answer (score 0):

Use an explicit `JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT r.Req_PK, r.Req_PostDate, r.Req_code, r.Req_CreateDate, r.Req_FillDate, 
       r.Req_Canceldate, r.Req_Hold, 
       cr.num_Applications, 
       r.Req_PublishstatusFK
FROM Req r JOIN
     (SELECT cr.CanReq_ReqFK, Count(*) as num_applications
      FROM CanReq cr
      GROUP BY cr.CanReq_ReqFK
     ) cr
     ON cr.CanReq_ReqFK = r.Req_PK
WHERE r.Req_Filled <> 1 AND r.Req_Cancelled <> 1 AND r.Req_Template <> 1 AND
      r.Req_PublishstatusFK = 1 AND r.Req_publishstatusfk = 1;
```

This will filter out any rows that don't have a record in `CanReq` -- the ones that would have a count of `0` in your version of the query.

I don't know why you would want the count to be a string.  Of course, you can include the conversion if you need it, but it doesn't seem necessary to me.

Comment: missing an alias on the derived table, and I think it might need to be a left join, but that's probably better than my answer....

Comment: @ZoharPeled . . . I think you are missing the intent of the question.  The OP wants to filter out rows that have no corresponding record.  The point of this answer is the `inner join`.  Thanks for noting the alias.

Comment: I might... It's getting quite late here so It's quite possible, but still - the OP is asking how to modify the Applications field, not the entire resultset....